# should I be using spray or play for highly scalable and efficient rest json processing?

Tags: json, rest, playframework, akka, spray

Should I be using play or spray for a highly efficient high throughput REST json server?
I would go with play because it would then allow me also to have a single framework both for REST and for web development.  However if spray is much much more efficient than this i would go with spray.

I would go immediately with play but i saw [here](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r6&hw=i7&test=json) that spray is high in the list and play is more to the bottom.

what do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, the complexity of managing two frameworks is going to far outweigh the slight performance improvement you might get from using spray.

It also depends on what features you need. Play is a full stack framework, which is why in simple scenarios, it's slower. If you implement some of the features built into Play on top of spray, you will probably end up worse off (performance, security, and capability wise) than if you just used Play.

Filter that benchmark list down to only full stack frameworks and you'll see that play is actually quite high on the list. Comparing full stack frameworks with micro frameworks is really quite misleading.